# How to Import and Export as a multidimensional array

Tags: matrix, export, import

I have 10000 matrices and each matrix is 3x3. So Dimensions[data] gives me {10000,3,3}. I saved this into a file with
Export["mydata.dat",data,"Table"]
Then when I imported it using
Import["mydata.dat","Table"], it gives me dimensions as {10000,9}.

How can I export and Import this as a list of dimensions {10000,3,3}?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: If you just need to read it back into mathematica on the same system use a ".mz" file.  If you need to share with other apps you should explain what you actually need.

Answer (score 8):

You can export as a MATLAB [`.mat` file](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html) if your array has less than 4 dimensions,

```
rand = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3, 3}];
Dimensions@rand
rand[[454, 1, 2]]
Export["random.mat", rand];
(* {1000, 3, 3} *)
(* 0.786307 *)
```

When you import it again, you have the same dimensions and the elements are the same

```
rand2 = Import["random.mat"];
Dimensions@rand2
rand2[[454, 1, 2]]
(* {1000, 3, 3} *)
(* 0.786307 *)
```

If you have 4 or more dimensions, you can export as an [HDF file](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF.html),

```
rand = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 4}];
Export["random.hdf", rand]
(* "random.hdf" *)
```

When you import it, it will tell you the names of the datasets stored in the file

```
Import["random.hdf"]
(* {"Dataset1"} *)
```

So when you import the data, you need to specify the dataset you are after,

```
rand2 = Import["random.hdf", {"Datasets", "Dataset1"}];
Dimensions@rand2
(* {1000, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 4} *)

rand == rand2
(* True *)
```

If you are exporting a lot of data, and don't need to read it with a text editor, then I would recommend always using one of these formats.  The file sizes will be drastically smaller and read times faster because they are binary formats.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It really worked !!!

Comment: @Jason B. How can I use ReadList to read the file because I have a very huge data to read?

Answer (score 5):

If you  plan to use your data in MMA only you can do

```
a = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3, 3}];
Dimensions[a]
a >> testExport.dat

b = << testExport.dat;
Dimensions[b]
a == b
```

Answer (score 5):

I absolutely support JasonB's suggestions, especially hdf5 seems a good format for such data when you want to be able to read with other software. But for the case where you only need to write and read with Mathematica, I think the MX format at least needs to be mentioned as well: it is by far the easiest and fastest way to store arbitrary expressions (not only higher dimension arrays):

```
a = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3, 3}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "tst.mx"}], a]
b = Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "tst.mx"}]];
a == b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for 3-dimensional arrays:

```
...
Dimensions[rcst]
  (* (45,31,19) *)
...
Export["rcst.dat", rcst, "Table"]
...
rcst1 = ToExpression[Import["rcst.dat", "TSV"]];
Max[Abs[rcst1 - rcst]]
  (* 0. *)
```

The point is that the imported array `rcst1` is 2-dimensional, and each element of it is a STRING rather than a 1-dimensional LIST, as it was in `rcst`.

The option `TSV` is to eliminate the double commas.